# Sea Monkeys air pump

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, brineshrimp, sea-monkeys

Can you please tell me where to look for the million bubble air pump or the oxy-mist air pump.  I cannot find it anywhere.  Or an alternative for my Sea Monkeys.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use any aquarium air pump, but most likely you will want a very small one. There's a number of online pet stores or your local big box or smaller local fish stores will carry them. The whisper brand pumps are decent and cost as little as about $5 or $6 for the model 10, which I would think would be plenty. Azoo, aqueon, and a few other manufacturers also make small cheap pumps. You may want to get a small inline valve at the same time in case the pump puts out too much air for what you need.